# Automatic restart of jar when property file is changed

Tags: spring-boot

I have a requirement where I am deploying a jar with its application.properties file outside of it. Is there any way that when I change an property in application.properties the jar automatically detects the changes and restarts/redeploys itself?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RefreshScope annotation is provided in spring-boot.
By use of this annotation, you can reload a property value(use inside your code) from .properties.

here is the link for reference :http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html (Search @RefreshScope).

The idea is to reload whole bean(which is annotated with @RefreshScope),after hitting /refresh end point & you do not need to restart webapp again.

Answer (score 0):

Read about http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

One of options is to restart/reload application after change in properties files.